# How to give permission to the users to only see tables under a dataset that they have access

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

```
|Project
  |-Dataset
    |-table1
    |-table2
```

I gave the following permissions on a Dataset level.

```
bigquery.datasets.get
bigquery.jobs.create
bigquery.jobs.list
resourcemanager.projects.get
```

and I gave the following only on table1

```
bigquery.tables.export
bigquery.tables.get
bigquery.tables.getData
bigquery.tables.list
```

Now user can query table1 but can't see the table1 under dataset in UI. it is as below:

```
|Project
      |-Dataset
```

And I would like to make it as below.

```
|Project
      |-Dataset
        |-table1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Compared to BigQuery basic role Data Viewer you are missing just a few permissions in comparison. I would try some of the missing ones like 
resourcemanager.projects.list  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.dataViewer

Comment: @MarcoMassetti that permission is not applicable. 
When I try to add it says: "Not applicable for project-level custom roles"

Comment: I guess that it is still not supported. Can you try to create a service account at the project level with the same permissions and then authorize your custom role to access that service account?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MarcoMassetti , but I need to give them on the user level, not over a service account.

Comment: Ah, ok. I cannot try it at the moment, but to test it, have you tried to assign the default Viewer role at the dataset/table level to see if it produces the expected result? If the custom role is the issue, maybe a combination of the two parts can hopefully help you

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I had to share only one table for user connecting with Google sheet in Bigquery.

Here is what I did to make this happen:

I created a new roles as follow:
**BigQuery Dataset Traverse**

```
With the following 6 assigned permissions
**bigquery.datasets.get
bigquery.jobs.create
bigquery.jobs.list
bigquery.tables.getData
bigquery.tables.list
resourcemanager.projects.get**
```

On ce created the new role, I created a group in Workspace and I granted access to this group at the project level to this group with the new role created.
The inheritance was propagated into the project to the tables level.

Finally, to permit user to read data into the table, I granted  this role **BigQuery Data Viewer** on my new group at the tables level.

And for sure, I added the user I need to have access into the new group.

Now they see all Dataset into the project, but they can only access data one table I shared.

Hope it s clear!

Cheer!

Comment: I needed this exactly! Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: I have noticed that bigquery.jobs.create can do anything to the data, read, update, delete. I am not sure if we have an extra permission somewhere but kinda an issue. Especially seeing as how there is a data editor role